# Does NXC work with EV3?

Tags: mindstorms, ev3, compatibility, nxc

Is it possible to create and run **NXC** programs on the **EV3** brick?

I installed BrixcCC, created a simple Hello World NXC program and selected "Download and Run" in the Compile menu.

The EV3 brick made a sound as if the program was downloaded; however, nothing happened on the EV3.

Very strange, but I was unable to find ANY good info on this subject on the web.

Would very much appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Not yet. You can try RobotC that's pretty similar.